# numerical values of coefficients

Tags: syntax, algebraic-manipulation, algebra

Consider the following output:

```
x= (Sqrt[3/(2 (1 + Sqrt[11]/4))] b[0, π/3] - (1 + Sqrt[7/3]) b[(2 π)/3, (2 π)/3])/(4 Sqrt[2] 7^(1/4) Sqrt[1 + Sqrt[7]/4])
```

If i do `N[x]` then I get rid of the annoying expressions for the coefficients of  `b[0, π/3],  b[(2 π)/3, (2 π)/3]` since they turn to decimal numbers but the same happens to the indices  `π/3, (2 π)/3` which I don't want.
This is just an example. Suppose you have many terms i.e:

```
a1 b[0, π/3] + a2 b[0,  π/2] + a3 b[π/12, 3 π/8] + ...
```

where the coefficients `a1, a2,...` have square roots, powers etc. How can I turn into decimals only `a1, a2,...` and not the indices of `b`

How can I turn into decimal numbers only the ugly coefficients?
I am trying to avoid `Expand` which is time consuming (at least in my case)

Comment: `x2 = Numerator[x]/N[Denominator[x]] // Expand` or `x2 = x /. Sqrt[a_] :> N[Sqrt[a]] // Expand`

Comment: @BobHanlon please see the edited question. Also `x2 = x /. Sqrt[a_] :> N[Sqrt[a]] // ` takes care only of the `Sqrt` not the power `7^1/4`

Comment: It works with the revised input. As long as there is any `Sqrt` with a numeric argument present, the replacement will  result in a machine number. Make sure you include the `Expand`.

Comment: `Expand` is very time consuming. That's what I am trying to avoid

Comment: Then edit your question to include your constraint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Without a representative example, I cannot tell how the timing compares with using `Expand`

```
x = (Sqrt[3/(2 (1 + Sqrt[11]/4))] b[
       0, π/3] - (1 + Sqrt[7/3]) b[(2 π)/3, (2 π)/3])/(4 Sqrt[
      2] 7^(1/4) Sqrt[1 + Sqrt[7]/4]);

var = Cases[x, b[__], Infinity];

x2 = Total[Chop[N[CoefficientList[x, var]]] . var]

(* 0.0763535 b[0, π/3] - 0.21311 b[(2 π)/3, (2 π)/3] *)
```

Answer (score 2):

[`NHoldAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NHoldAll.html) is designed for this.

```
ClearAll[b];
SetAttributes[b, NHoldAll];
x = (Sqrt[3/(2 (1 + Sqrt[11]/4))] b[0, π/3] - 
      (1 + Sqrt[7/3]) b[(2 π)/3, (2 π)/3]) /
     (4 Sqrt[2] 7^(1/4) Sqrt[1 + Sqrt[7]/4]);

N[x]
(*
0.0843157 (0.905566 b[0, π/3] - 
   2.52753 b[(2 π)/3, (2 π)/3])
*)
```

There are also [`NHoldFirst`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NHoldFirst.html) and [`NHoldRest`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NHoldRest.html).

Comment: thanks! I will check it

Answer (score 1):

As simple as

```
Collect[x, _b, N]
```

Comment: I forgot to include the output of the command. It is `0.07635345378337137*b[0, Pi/3] - 
 0.21311006101665048*b[(2*Pi)/3, (2*Pi)/3]`

Answer (score 0):

What worked better than `Expand` for `x` consisting of a large number of terms like the ones above is:

```
rules = {Sqrt[a_] :> N[Sqrt[a]], a_/b_ :> N[a/b] /; Mod[a, π] != 0, 
Power[x_, y_] :> N[x^y]};
```

Sorry I couldn't post a specific example for `x` as it consists of more than 20 terms added.

Comment: What I usually do if I can't set `NHoldAll` on the function (e.g. `Sin[1]`) is something like this: `x /. {bb_b :> bb, n_?NumericQ :> N[n]}`. Rules like `yy_h :> yy` at the beginning of the list of rules replaces any expression `yy` that has a head `h` by itself.  None of the rules that follow will be applied to `yy` or to its subexpressions.